# Access violation reading location using GTest without any complicated testing

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, object, googletest

I got stucked for a week on a problem that I cannot solve by my own.

DESCRIPTION:
My boss decided to implement C++ objects in C language, because he likes GTesting method (that cant use 90% of it's possibilities, because C doesn't containt objects).
I did it like wise people did in this website : http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~beardj/Mixed_C_C++.html

I used them in bigger function, where it works great, without any problems, no memory leaks, nothing... Fake functions are called via interface perfectly.

Problem cames when I want to apply GTest on this function, that calls these C++ objects via interface (dual purpose header), or even when I want to call GTest at all.

Here are source codes:

This is file including all GTest and GMock methods. It is common file that works elsewhere.

**InitGMock.h**

```
#ifndef INITGMOCK_H_
#define INITGMOCK_H_


#include "GTest/gtest.h"
#include "GMock/gmock.h"


#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(P)      (void)(P)

using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::Cardinality;
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::An;
using ::testing::A;
using ::testing::Ge;
using ::testing::Eq;
using ::testing::InSequence;
using ::testing::internal::ExpectationTester;

... and so on, using all testing methods
```

This is main cpp file.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "InitGMock.h"  
extern "C"
{
#include "LPAll_Testing_3.h" //all includes from C files
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

::testing::TestEventListeners& listeners = ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
listeners.Append(new MemoryLeakListener);


RUN_ALL_TESTS();

getchar(); // keep console window open until Return keystroke 
return 0;
}
```

and here are my tests

**Tests.cpp**

```
#include "LPAll_Testing_3.h"
#include "InitGMock.h"

TEST(oLocalPsiTestingClass, FirstTest) 
{

    EXPECT_EQ(7,7);
}
```

What I have figured out by now:
1. From time to time program doesn't crash, test is made (but fails).

1. When test fails, it fails in `dbghook.c` file
2. TEST() is called twice, for reason I dont know. First immediately after program start, second after `RUN_ALL_TESTS();` command
3. Error after when program ends:
   First-chance exception at 0x0047aae0 in LP_Testing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccc1c.
   unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.
4. I tried to use other main signatures:

   - int main(int argc, char **argv)  //ORIGINAL
   - //int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   - //int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

but no one is working correctly

If someone has idea how to solve this, I would be incredibly happy, because I am starting to be desperate. :-)

Thanks, have a nice day. If you will need some other informations or source codes, ask. :-)

EDIT:
I found another strange issue.
When I call macro `EXPECT_EQ(7,7)` it throws error `There is no source code available for the current location.` - VS2005 error message. I have included gtest.lib and gmock.lib (and and directory where they are), so it should see this command. Also when I want to see declaration & definition of this it will redirect me to gtest.h

Comment: 'My boss decided to implement C++ objects in C language' - update your CV and start emailing:)

Comment: True.. But I like it here. They feed me with cofee for free.. :D

Comment: Are you putting your tests into a library? Check https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users then.

Comment: I tried as you instructed me, Vlad. But, unfortunatelly, the same error result appeared.. But thanks for answering. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I managed some solution, but it is at least NOT STABLE...

First, I tried to add some "dummy" test:

```
TEST(DummyObject,FirstTest)
{
EXPECT_TRUE(TRUE);
}
```

Then clean and rebuild solution.
After this procedure solution recognized that problematic commands, but it is still not working correctly -  a lot of memory leaks, test are sometimes evaluated incorrectly and so on.

Guys, be aware of testing C++ object viac C interface in C++ UnitTesting tool!!! :D